# ASP.NET ListView enable options for edit,delete,insert

Tags: asp.net, listview

I try to write a simple web application using ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2015.

I have add a ListView and SQLDataSource on a WebForm.
The SQLDataSource is connected to a database.
Displaying data in the ListView works, also paging.

Now I also want to test editing, inserting and deleting.
However when I open "ListView Tasks" and "Configure ListView"  the options for

Enable Editing
Enable Inserting
Enable Deleting

are disabled.

[image]

How can I enabled these options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the insert, update, or delete commands specified in your datasource. Good tutorial can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515103.aspx